# How to change activityBar :active and :hover styles?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out how I can change the styles for `hover` and `active` states on the `ActivityBar`.

The [Activity Bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_activity-bar) reference does not mention how to change the styles for these states.

Using the developer tools I saw that the styles are applied to `.action-item` elements.

Answer (score 0):

The [reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_activity-bar) you linked documents how to change the *color* of `activityBar.foreground`, which is used for the currently open side bar activity (if any) and for the icon under the mouse (if any), i.e., both "active" and "hover", if I understand your terminology.

There isn't a way to give them two distinct colors.

You also cannot make arbitrary style changes to themable elements, you can only change their color.  Even [extensions do not have arbitrary DOM access](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview#no-dom-access), so cannot re-style activity bar elements.